# Utilizar la autenticación de Azure AD en una aplicación web

Tags: web, app, azure, autenticación

Actualmente estoy trabajando en una aplicación web para cierta empresa, dicha aplicación requiere de un inicio de sesión para acceder. Sin embargo, ellos usan Azure AD y requiero conectarme a ella.

La aplicación esta bastante avanzada, de hecho ya tiene un login que permite acceso a través de una base de datos, lo que yo requiero es utilizar esta DB como filtro. En otras palabra el usuario ingresa se verifica que se encuentre en la base de datos y de ser así solicita a Azure la autorización para acceder a la aplicación.

He buscado documentación pero la mayoría implementa el inicio de sesión de Azure para permitir el acceso a la app.... como por ejemplo https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-sign-in?tabs=java.

Comment: Favor agrega link de referencias a documentación de la tecnología o fragmentos de código en donde necesites la solución.

Comment: En el link esta la documentación oficial... pero he realizado varias búsquedas y encuentro cosas similares. Lo implemente tal cual y me funciona pero no es lo que necesito

Comment: Hola mira creo que deberías leer https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code , la logica seria crear un ID de autorizacion por usuario ( algun modulo para sincronizar cuenta de azure ) con ese token podra realizar peticiones a la informacion del usuario en nuevas peticiones sin volver a solicitar sincronzación.